# How to make grids on maps plotted using ggmap in R

Tags: r, ggmap

Please pardon me if this is a redundant question. I am new to R. I was going through this post- http://www.r-bloggers.com/mapping-gps-tracks-in-r/. It maps the gps tracks in R using ggmap. My question is that, once we have the final map, is it possible to put grids on it? If yes, how to do it?

EDIT- Ok let me rephrase my question... suppose I have plotted some gps coordinate on a map. Then how to put grid over it? Let me take the example of one of the question already solved here at stack overflow by Cory: [Plotting GPS coordinates using ggmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374505/plotting-gps-coordinates-using-ggmap)
Here`s the final map:-
[image]

Now my question is how to get a grid structure on this map?
TIA!

TIA!

Regards,
Lesnar

Comment: On mobile, but did you get a chance to review the documentation?

Comment: You mean, the ggmap package document?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - put ggplot grid lines in foreground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054092/r-put-ggplot-grid-lines-in-foreground)

Comment: That looks like it is what lesnar is looking for, however since its about maps, I presume that lesnar would like it to scale with the size of the map.

Comment: @BobtheBuilder yes, exactly! That`s what I am looking for. Can this be done for maps as well?

Comment: you should add (including your dataset) to your post what you have tried so far.

Comment: @MLavoie ok.. have done it now!

Comment: something like that  (ggmap(mapImageData) + geom_point(aes(x = lon,y = lat),data = gps,colour = "red",size = 1,pch = 20))  + geom_vline(xintercept=seq(-4.020, -4.017, by=0.0001)) + geom_hline(yintercept=seq(53.2, 53.25, by=0.001))

Comment: @MLavoie Got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MLavoie Perhaps a variable that determines the scale of the grid based on a calculation of the image resolution?

Comment: @lesnar Do your maps have a "scale" built in? As-in, "Map of New York" and part of the qualitative data associated with it says "2:1 scale". If so, then you can create a quick equation to extrapolate the scale of your grid.

Comment: @BobtheBuilder There`s no  "scale" built in my map. But I get it what you mean here. Thanks!